# Return statement is not returning correct value

Tags: java, android

```
public static String getFirstLangScore(CRSDatabase db) {
         String firstLanguageScore = "";
        if (mGlobals.getSelectLanguage().equals("ENGLISH")) {
            String[] lowestEnglishReading = mGlobals.getEnglishReadingScore().split("CLB ");            
            firstLanguageScore = //did some calculation and updated the value

        }
        else if(mGlobals.getSelectLanguage().equals("FRENCH")){
            String[] lowestFrenchReading = mGlobals.getFrenchReadingScore().split("CLB ");

            firstLanguageScore = // did some calculation and updated the value

        }
        return firstLanguageScore;  // here it is returning the initial initialized value.

    }
```

I am calling this method from an asynctask, but it is not returning the updated value, rather than it is returning me "" which is its initialization value at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the AsyncTask usage

Comment: Also, do some debugging, please. We don't know what `mGlobals.getSelectLanguage()` is equal to, so are your if statements working as expected?

Comment: mGlobals.getSelectLanguage() is simply returning a String , which is working fine when I debugged. And my if statement is also working as expected. Only the return statement is not working as expected.

Comment: Try debugging the code and see what is happening. And one of my interpretation is that if `mGlobals.getSelectLanguage()` is neither "ENGLISH" nor "FRENCH" then there is no `else` condition to handle it. So, by default the `firstLanguageScore` is an empty string.

Comment: This code alone doesn't look like it needs an AsyncTask at all, so your question is not clear. If you think that the return statement is broken, then it's recommended you do unit tests to verify that behavior

Comment: @Kavin Prabhu looks like that is the issue, let me debug more on it and will find the answer.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cricket_007 that's why I did not post the AsyncTask code here as it has nothing to do with it. And already debugging to find the solution..will get back with the solution soon.

Comment: If you want help here, you need to post it, as this code alone works absolutely fine assuming the if statements are working... If you modify your string within an AsyncTask, then this method will return **before** the AsyncTask finished

Comment: Got any lead for the issue?

Comment: yes, I got the actual reason. It was actually the if-else condition which was not correctly executing. As there were no else part it was returning the default value. I corrected that and it was done. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It was a great help. @Kavin Prabhu

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestion..Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you use an asynchronous thread to process the data, but you really want to get the data in the main thread, but you open this task in the main thread, the asynchronous thread has not yet obtained the corresponding value, the main thread Got this variable

please try it

```
public void getFirstLangScore(CRSDatabase db,DataCallback dataBack) { 

String firstLanguageScore = "";

if (mGlobals.getSelectLanguage().equals("ENGLISH")) {
    String[] lowestEnglishReading = mGlobals.getEnglishReadingScore().split("CLB ");


    firstLanguageScore = //did some calculation and updated the value

}
else if(mGlobals.getSelectLanguage().equals("FRENCH")){
    String[] lowestFrenchReading = mGlobals.getFrenchReadingScore().split("CLB ");

    firstLanguageScore = // did some calculation and updated the value

}
 databack.returnLanguageScore(firstLanguageScore );
}

/**
*DataCallBack
*/
public interface DataCallback {
   void returnLanguageScore(String data);
}
```

Invoke the asynchronous method in the main thread and pass in DataCallBack. Implement its interface, waiting for an asynchronous callback，
or you can user Handler to solve it

Comment: While overall correct, I think question is doing async work within `did some calculation` comments